# how to have text of 2 font sizes in same line in HTML?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a front end HTML page using bootstrap and basic HTML code. I need to print price of a particular product say $63.
I want this to be in same line but the size of $ needs to be smaller than the number. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```css
 span { font-size: 3em;}
 span b { font-size: 60%; font-weight: normal }
```

```html
<span><b>$</b>63</span>
```

---

You could also avoid to use a nested element to wrap the currency sign and use the `::first-letter` pseudoclass to style it, but this requires a `block` or `inline-block` parent element, e.g.

```css
span { 
   font-size: 3em; 
   display: inline-block; }

span::first-letter { font-size: 60%; }
```

```html
<span>$63</span>
```

Comment: I think for this question `vertical-align:;` is also important. Here are some examples based on your answer: http://codepen.io/Nico_O/pen/AfGwr

Answer (score 8):

Only HTML: using

1. Two span tags and 2. different font size in style

   ```html
   <span style="font-size: 25px;">Rs</span> <span style="font-size: 50px;">2000/-</span>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/RPf4N/2/

html

```
<div id="mydiv">$<a>63</a></div>
```

ur css

```
#mydiv
{
    font-size:20px;
}
#mydiv a
{
    font-size:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @Abhishek answer.
I was able to leverage the < a > tag to add multiple font size to a single HighCharts label inline like:
..."label":"abc
def",

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35603933)