# Change font of one word / substring in line of text in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

In my shiny app, I've got a css file to sort out the styling for most things. However, I'm struggling with one element, which is that I want the font of one word to be changed within a line of text.

I know how to change some elements, such as making it bold or a different colour,  but I'd like it to be a different font, and that doesn't seem to be as obvious. If I try something like that just for one word, I end up with the HTML printed as it isn't doing anything. I'm not very familiar with HTML or css so I might be missing something, but can't find a question on here with the same specific issue.

Here is example code:

**UI**

```
htmlOutput("example_text)
```

**Server**

```
function(input, output, session) {
output$example_text <- renderUI({
                                paste0("I want to make ", "this", " a different font")
                               })
}
```

**Server v2 (makes the word bold but doesn't change the font family)**

```
function(input, output, session) {
output$example_text <- renderUI({
         HTML(paste0("I want to make ", 
              "<font-family=\"Courier New\"><b>", "this", "</font></b>",
              " a different font")
              )
                               })
}
```

Comment: Consider using [`HTML(...)`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.2.0/HTML.html), solving your problem with CSS or other html-specific method instead, including https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

Comment: That is one of the things I have tried to do, but I clearly don't understand what the right way to approach it is as it doesn't work. I'll edit my answer to show exactly what I've done.

Comment: The link I provided is using a *CSS style* to define `font-family`, not an HTML tag as you have in your updated question. If you go to a sibling web page https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp, they suggest that *"The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5"*, so you should lean towards a CSS solution.

Comment: OK, but I don't understand how to do that for one individual part of a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i see you could try using `HTML()`, but you would run into the problem of keeping the text in one line.
You could get some help here: [how to have text of 2 font sizes in same line in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634874/how-to-have-text-of-2-font-sizes-in-same-line-in-html).

The css you can add with `tags$style()`:

```
  tags$style('
    #mydiv{font-family:"Arial";}
    #mydiv b{font-family:"Courier New";}
  '),
```

The full code would read:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style('
    #mydiv{font-family:"Arial";}
    #mydiv b{font-family:"Courier New";}'),
  htmlOutput("example_text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$example_text <- renderUI({
    HTML("<div id='mydiv'>I want to make <b>this</b> a new font.</div>")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is great, and I've added the css to my css file.